# Saving the value of an entry, after user input, in a repeating function

Tags: python, tkinter

> Hi, my name is Chris and my code is a little all over the place, this
> is also my first time asking a question. So my problem is that i have
> a button that when pressed will run a function each time pressed, this
> function creates 3 entry's next to one anther, where the user is
> expected to entre the appropriate information in each entry box, my
> problem is i added a button that when pressed is suppose to pull the
> value from each existing entry row and save it, where i want to later
> use it to do equations. My problem is that since i am repeating the
> entry's, they are not unique each time but rather a clone so i cant
> seem to tell the program to find each entry, since they are clones of
> one another, or at least thats what i think.
>
> i have tried many different ways of saving the values so here is each
> method i tried:
>
> Here is a the part of my code without the code where i try saving the
> value:

```
import tkinter as tk
Window4 = tk.Tk()
Window4.title("Budget Program")
Window4.geometry("700x400")
windowWidth = Window4.winfo_reqwidth()
windowHeight = Window4.winfo_reqheight()
positionRight = int(Window4.winfo_screenwidth() / 2 - windowWidth / 2)
positionDown = int(Window4.winfo_screenheight() / 2 - windowHeight / 2)
Window4.geometry("+{}+{}".format(positionRight, positionDown))

class App(object):
    def new_row(self):

        v = tk.StringVar()

        entry_Box = tk.Entry(Window4, width=15, textvariable=v)
        name = entry_Box.insert(0, "Name of income")

        entry_Box2 = tk.Entry(Window4, width=8)
        amount = entry_Box2.insert(0, "Amount")

        rate = OptionList = [
        "Hourly",
        "Daily",
        "Weekly",
        "Monthly"
        ]
        variable = tk.StringVar(Window4)
        variable.set(OptionList[0])

        opt = tk.OptionMenu(Window4, variable, *OptionList)
        opt.config(width=5, font=('Helvetica', 6))

        blank = tk.Label(Window4, text="  ")

        # Put widgets in grid
        self.num_rows += 1
        self.num_rows2 += 1
        self.num_rows3 += 1
        self.num_rows4 += 1

        opt.grid(column=3, row=self.num_rows3)
        opt.bind("<Button-1>")

        entry_Box.grid(column=0, row=self.num_rows)
        def some_callback(event):
            entry_Box.delete(0, "end")
            return None
        entry_Box.bind("<Button-1>", some_callback)

        entry_Box2.grid(column=1, row=self.num_rows2)
        def some_callback(event):
            entry_Box2.delete(0, "end")
            return None
        entry_Box2.bind("<Button-1>", some_callback)

        blank.grid(column=6, row=self.num_rows4, padx=160)

    def __init__(self):
        self.num_rows = 1
        self.num_rows2 = 1
        self.num_rows3 = 1
        self.num_rows4 = 1
        createRow_button = tk.Button(
                Window4, text='Add income row', command=self.new_row)
        createRow_button.place(x=240, y=0)
app = App()
Window4.mainloop()
```

> I first tried to simply use the .get() function:

```
import tkinter as tk
Window4 = tk.Tk()
Window4.title("Budget Program")
Window4.geometry("700x400")
windowWidth = Window4.winfo_reqwidth()
windowHeight = Window4.winfo_reqheight()
positionRight = int(Window4.winfo_screenwidth() / 2 - windowWidth / 2)
positionDown = int(Window4.winfo_screenheight() / 2 - windowHeight / 2)
Window4.geometry("+{}+{}".format(positionRight, positionDown))
class App(object):
    def new_row(self):
        new_entry = tk.Entry(Window4, width=15)
        name = new_entry.insert(0, "Name of income")

        new_entry2 = tk.Entry(Window4, width=8)
        amount = new_entry2.insert(0, "Amount")

        rate = OptionList = [
        "Hourly",
        "Daily",
        "Weekly",
        "Monthly"
        ]
        variable = tk.StringVar(Window4)
        variable.set(OptionList[0])

        opt = tk.OptionMenu(Window4, variable, *OptionList)
        opt.config(width=5, font=('Helvetica', 6))

        blank = tk.Label(Window4, text="  ")

        # Put widgets in grid
        self.num_rows += 1
        self.num_rows2 += 1
        self.num_rows3 += 1
        self.num_rows4 += 1
        opt.grid(column=3, row=self.num_rows3)
        opt.bind("<Button-1>")

        new_entry.grid(column=0, row=self.num_rows)
        def some_callback(event):
            new_entry.delete(0, "end")
            return None
        new_entry.bind("<Button-1>", some_callback)

        new_entry2.grid(column=1, row=self.num_rows2)
        def some_callback(event):
            new_entry2.delete(0, "end")
            return None
        new_entry2.bind("<Button-1>", some_callback)

        blank.grid(column=6, row=self.num_rows4, padx=160)

        return name
        return amount
        return rate

    def __init__(self):
        self.num_rows = 1
        self.num_rows2 = 1
        self.num_rows3 = 1
        self.num_rows4 = 1
        createRow_button = tk.Button(
                Window4, text='Add income row', command=self.new_row)
        createRow_button.place(x=240, y=0)
app = App()

def budget(name, amount, rate):

    nameincome = name.get()
    print(nameincome)

    amountincome = amount.get()
    print(amountincome)

    rateincome = rate.get()
    print(rateincome)

Submitlabel = tk.Label(Window4, text="When you are done click below to work out your budget.", )
Submitlabel.place(x=240, y=40)

Submitbtn = tk.Button(Window4, text="Submit", command=lambda: budget(name, amount, rate))
Submitbtn.place(x=365, y=90)

Window4.mainloop()
```

> But got the error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Meyerc2/.PyCharmEdu2019.3/config/scratches/scratch_5.py", line 82, in <lambda>
    Submitbtn = tk.Button(Window4, text="Submit", command=lambda: budget(name, amount, rate))
NameError: name 'name' is not defined
```

> Then i tried to get the value straight from the entry and not the
> variable name:

```
import tkinter as tk
Window4 = tk.Tk()
Window4.title("Budget Program")
Window4.geometry("700x400")
windowWidth = Window4.winfo_reqwidth()
windowHeight = Window4.winfo_reqheight()
positionRight = int(Window4.winfo_screenwidth() / 2 - windowWidth / 2)
positionDown = int(Window4.winfo_screenheight() / 2 - windowHeight / 2)
Window4.geometry("+{}+{}".format(positionRight, positionDown))


class App(object):
    def new_row(self):
        new_entry = tk.Entry(Window4, width=15)
        name = new_entry.insert(0, "Name of income")

        new_entry2 = tk.Entry(Window4, width=8)
        amount = new_entry2.insert(0, "Amount")

        rate = OptionList = [
            "Hourly",
            "Daily",
            "Weekly",
            "Monthly"
        ]
        variable = tk.StringVar(Window4)
        variable.set(OptionList[0])
        opt = tk.OptionMenu(Window4, variable, *OptionList)
        opt.config(width=5, font=('Helvetica', 6))

        blank = tk.Label(Window4, text="  ")

        # Put widgets in grid
        self.num_rows += 1
        self.num_rows2 += 1
        self.num_rows3 += 1
        self.num_rows4 += 1
        opt.grid(column=3, row=self.num_rows3)
        opt.bind("<Button-1>")

        new_entry.grid(column=0, row=self.num_rows)

        def some_callback(event):
            new_entry.delete(0, "end")
            return None
        new_entry.bind("<Button-1>", some_callback)

        new_entry2.grid(column=1, row=self.num_rows2)

        def some_callback(event):
            new_entry2.delete(0, "end")
            return None
        new_entry2.bind("<Button-1>", some_callback)

        blank.grid(column=6, row=self.num_rows4, padx=160)

        return new_entry, new_entry2, variable

    def __init__(self):
        self.num_rows = 1
        self.num_rows2 = 1
        self.num_rows3 = 1
        self.num_rows4 = 1
        createRow_button = tk.Button(
            Window4, text='Add income row', command=self.new_row)
        assert isinstance(createRow_button, object)
        createRow_button.place(x=240, y=0)


app = App()


def budget(new_entry, new_entry2, variable):
    nameincome = new_entry.get()
    print(nameincome)

    amountincome = new_entry2.get()
    print(amountincome)

    rateincome = variable.get()
    print(rateincome)


Submitlabel = tk.Label(Window4, text="When you are done click below to work out your budget.", )
Submitlabel.place(x=240, y=40)

Submitbtn = tk.Button(Window4, text="Submit", command=lambda: budget(new_entry, new_entry2, variable))
Submitbtn.place(x=365, y=90)

Window4.mainloop()
```

> But got the error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Meyerc2/.PyCharmEdu2019.3/config/scratches/scratch_5.py", line 87, in <lambda>
    Submitbtn = tk.Button(Window4, text="Submit", command=lambda: budget(new_entry, new_entry2, variable))
NameError: name 'new_entry' is not defined
```

> Next i tried to save it to a list:

```
import tkinter as tk

Window4 = tk.Tk()
Window4.title("Budget Program")
Window4.geometry("700x400")
windowWidth = Window4.winfo_reqwidth()
windowHeight = Window4.winfo_reqheight()
positionRight = int(Window4.winfo_screenwidth() / 2 - windowWidth / 2)
positionDown = int(Window4.winfo_screenheight() / 2 - windowHeight / 2)
Window4.geometry("+{}+{}".format(positionRight, positionDown))


class App(object):
    def new_row(self):
        v = tk.StringVar()
        new_entry = tk.Entry(Window4, width=15, textvariable=v)
        name = new_entry.insert(0, "Name of income")

        mylist = []

        new_entry2 = tk.Entry(Window4, width=8)
        amount = new_entry2.insert(0, "Amount")

        rate = OptionList = [
            "Hourly",
            "Daily",
            "Weekly",
            "Monthly"
        ]
        variable = tk.StringVar(Window4)
        variable.set(OptionList[0])
        opt = tk.OptionMenu(Window4, variable, *OptionList)
        opt.config(width=5, font=('Helvetica', 6))

        blank = tk.Label(Window4, text="  ")

        # Put widgets in grid
        self.num_rows += 1
        self.num_rows2 += 1
        self.num_rows3 += 1
        self.num_rows4 += 1
        opt.grid(column=3, row=self.num_rows3)
        opt.bind("<Button-1>")

        new_entry.grid(column=0, row=self.num_rows)

        def some_callback(event):
            new_entry.delete(0, "end")
            return None

        new_entry.bind("<Button-1>", some_callback)

        new_entry2.grid(column=1, row=self.num_rows2)

        def some_callback(event):
            new_entry2.delete(0, "end")
            return None

        new_entry2.bind("<Button-1>", some_callback)

        blank.grid(column=6, row=self.num_rows4, padx=160)

        mylist.append(name)
        mylist.append(amount)
        mylist.append(rate)
        return new_entry, new_entry2, rate

    def __init__(self):
        self.num_rows = 1
        self.num_rows2 = 1
        self.num_rows3 = 1
        self.num_rows4 = 1
        createRow_button = tk.Button(
            Window4, text='Add income row', command=self.new_row)
        createRow_button.place(x=240, y=0)


app = App()

new_entry2 = ''
rate = ''


def income():
    nameincome = App.new_row().find(App.new_row())
    amountincome = App.new_entry2.get()
    rateincome = App.rate

    print(nameincome, amountincome, rateincome)


btn = tk.Button(Window4, text="go", command=lambda: income())
btn.place(x=270, y=0)

Submitlabel = tk.Label(Window4, text="When you are done click below to work out your budget.", )
Submitlabel.place(x=240, y=40)

Window4.mainloop()
```

> But got the error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Meyerc2/.PyCharmEdu2019.3/config/scratches/scratch_5.py", line 92, in <lambda>
    btn = tk.Button(Window4, text="go", command=lambda: income())
  File "C:/Users/Meyerc2/.PyCharmEdu2019.3/config/scratches/scratch_5.py", line 85, in income
    nameincome = App.new_row().find(App.new_row())
TypeError: new_row() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

> Next i tried using the App() function to get the value out of the class so that i can use it inside a function:

```
import tkinter as tk

Window4 = tk.Tk()
Window4.title("Budget Program")
Window4.geometry("700x400")
windowWidth = Window4.winfo_reqwidth()
windowHeight = Window4.winfo_reqheight()
positionRight = int(Window4.winfo_screenwidth() / 2 - windowWidth / 2)
positionDown = int(Window4.winfo_screenheight() / 2 - windowHeight / 2)
Window4.geometry("+{}+{}".format(positionRight, positionDown))


class App(object):
    def new_row(self):
        v = tk.StringVar()
        new_entry = tk.Entry(Window4, width=15, textvariable=v)
        name = new_entry.insert(0, "Name of income")

        mylist = []

        new_entry2 = tk.Entry(Window4, width=8)
        amount = new_entry2.insert(0, "Amount")

        rate = OptionList = [
            "Hourly",
            "Daily",
            "Weekly",
            "Monthly"
        ]
        variable = tk.StringVar(Window4)
        variable.set(OptionList[0])
        opt = tk.OptionMenu(Window4, variable, *OptionList)
        opt.config(width=5, font=('Helvetica', 6))

        blank = tk.Label(Window4, text="  ")

        # Put widgets in grid
        self.num_rows += 1
        self.num_rows2 += 1
        self.num_rows3 += 1
        self.num_rows4 += 1
        opt.grid(column=3, row=self.num_rows3)
        opt.bind("<Button-1>")

        new_entry.grid(column=0, row=self.num_rows)

        def some_callback(event):
            new_entry.delete(0, "end")
            return None

        new_entry.bind("<Button-1>", some_callback)

        new_entry2.grid(column=1, row=self.num_rows2)

        def some_callback(event):
            new_entry2.delete(0, "end")
            return None

        new_entry2.bind("<Button-1>", some_callback)

        blank.grid(column=6, row=self.num_rows4, padx=160)

        mylist.append(name)
        mylist.append(amount)
        mylist.append(rate)
        return new_entry, new_entry2, rate

    def __init__(self):
        self.num_rows = 1
        self.num_rows2 = 1
        self.num_rows3 = 1
        self.num_rows4 = 1
        createRow_button = tk.Button(
            Window4, text='Add income row', command=self.new_row)
        createRow_button.place(x=240, y=0)

app = App()

new_entry2 = ''
rate = ''
def income():

    nameincome = App.new_row().find(App.new_row())
    amountincome = App.new_entry2.get()
    rateincome = App.rate

    print(nameincome, amountincome, rateincome)

btn = tk.Button(Window4, text="go", command=lambda: income())
btn.place(x=270, y=0)


Submitlabel = tk.Label(Window4, text="When you are done click below to work out your budget.", )
Submitlabel.place(x=240, y=40)

Window4.mainloop()
```

> And got the error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Meyerc2/.PyCharmEdu2019.3/config/scratches/scratch_5.py", line 89, in <lambda>
    btn = tk.Button(Window4, text="go", command=lambda: income())
  File "C:/Users/Meyerc2/.PyCharmEdu2019.3/config/scratches/scratch_5.py", line 83, in income
    nameincome = App.new_row().find(App.new_row())
TypeError: new_row() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

> Now i am trying to make a unique name per entry using increments in
> order to perhaps be able to save it:

```
    import tkinter as tk
Window4 = tk.Tk()
Window4.title("Budget Program")
Window4.geometry("700x400")
windowWidth = Window4.winfo_reqwidth()
windowHeight = Window4.winfo_reqheight()
positionRight = int(Window4.winfo_screenwidth() / 2 - windowWidth / 2)
positionDown = int(Window4.winfo_screenheight() / 2 - windowHeight / 2)
Window4.geometry("+{}+{}".format(positionRight, positionDown))


class App(object):
    def new_row(self):

        Unique_Val = 0
        Unique_Val_A = 0

        v = tk.StringVar()
        entry_Box = "new_entry{}".format(Unique_Val)
        entry_Box = tk.Entry(Window4, width=15, textvariable=v)
        name = entry_Box.insert(0, "Name of income")
        Unique_Val += 1

        entry_Box2 = "new_entry2{}".format(Unique_Val_A)
        entry_Box2 = tk.Entry(Window4, width=8)
        amount = entry_Box2.insert(0, "Amount")
        Unique_Val_A += 1

        rate = OptionList = [
        "Hourly",
        "Daily",
        "Weekly",
        "Monthly"
        ]
        variable = tk.StringVar(Window4)
        variable.set(OptionList[0])

        opt = tk.OptionMenu(Window4, variable, *OptionList)
        opt.config(width=5, font=('Helvetica', 6))

        blank = tk.Label(Window4, text="  ")

        # Put widgets in grid
        self.num_rows += 1
        self.num_rows2 += 1
        self.num_rows3 += 1
        self.num_rows4 += 1

        opt.grid(column=3, row=self.num_rows3)
        opt.bind("<Button-1>")

        entry_Box.grid(column=0, row=self.num_rows)
        def some_callback(event):
            entry_Box.delete(0, "end")
            return None
        entry_Box.bind("<Button-1>", some_callback)

        entry_Box2.grid(column=1, row=self.num_rows2)
        def some_callback(event):
            entry_Box2.delete(0, "end")
            return None
        entry_Box2.bind("<Button-1>", some_callback)

        blank.grid(column=6, row=self.num_rows4, padx=160)

        return entry_Box, entry_Box2, rate

    def save(self):
        name1 = self.entry_Box.get()
        amount1 = self.entry_Box2.get()

        mylist = []
        mylist.append(name1)
        mylist.append(amount1)

        print(mylist)


    def __init__(self):
        self.num_rows = 1
        self.num_rows2 = 1
        self.num_rows3 = 1
        self.num_rows4 = 1
        createRow_button = tk.Button(
                Window4, text='Add income row', command=self.new_row)
        createRow_button.place(x=240, y=0)
        savebtn = tk.Button(Window4, text="save", command=self.save)
        savebtn.place(x=240, y=50)

app = App()

Window4.mainloop()
```

> But i get the error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Meyerc2/.PyCharmEdu2019.3/config/scratches/scratch_1.py", line 69, in save
    name1 = self.entry_Box.get()
AttributeError: 'App' object has no attribute 'entry_Box'
```

> If you need any other information i am happy to help, i also have a
> GitHub if that is needed, i can also give my Whole code if necessary,
> I am using pycharm.

Comment: Your repeating the same code again here in the post, strip down the code and just include whats important while you explain your different approaches.

Comment: Maybe try appending it to the list and use indexing on the list to call the required item?

Comment: @ChrisBoss I'm not gonna lie it looks like there is quite a bit wrong with your code, but I can try and help. Your first error is because the variable 'name' is only available in the scope of the function 'new_row'. First off I'd suggest you put the __init__ function first in the class and have all the variables you are going to use listed there i.e. `self.name = entry_Box.insert(0, "Name of income")` and then access it by using `app.name`. Also, why do you have return statements in a class?

Comment: Ive added an answer, do let me know

Comment: You've posted far too much code. You need to replace all of that code with a [mcve] created specifically for this question, and you need to focus on only a single problem at a time.

Comment: It work thank you so much @CoolCloud, months of work and the end is in sight, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm adding this just so you get an idea on what to or what to do, This is prolly just one of the ways on how to proceed.

Basically, just create two empty lists in the `__init__` call and then append these entry widgets to those lists created earlier, like:

```
def __init__(self):
    .....#same bunch of code
    self.lst1 = []
    self.lst2 = []
```

and then at the end of your `new_row()` method, say:

```
def new_row():
    ....#same bunch of codes

    self.lst1.append(entry_Box)
    self.lst2.append(entry_Box2)
```

Now this way to access the entry widget, say `print(lst1[0].get())`. This will returns whats inside the first box in the first column. `print(lst2[0].get())` will return whats inside the first box in the second column, this way, you get a pattern of a matrix type arrangement and can easily get the values like this.

Though I recommend to remove the binding to the entry widgets as they will just create problems for you later on, if you are looking on creating placeholders with tkinter entry widgets, take a look [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/250083/python-tkinter-placeholder-class). Not the perfect of classes, but still will get the job done.

**Also keep in mind `name` and `amount` are useless as they are `None`, so there is not point in using those.**